# Is $N_R$ a Majorana field in the Seesaw Lagrangian?

Tags: particle-physics, neutrinos, beyond-the-standard-model, majorana-fermions, charge-conjugation

Consider the Lagrangian for the type-I seesaw given by
$$-\mathcal{L}=\bar{\nu}_{L}m_DN_{R}+\frac{1}{2}\overline{(N_{R})^c}M_R N_{R}+\text{h.c.}.$$

$\bullet$ In this Lagrangian, what is the nature of $N_R$ field? I think it cannot be Majorana **even though** we write a Majorana mass for it because we don't take $(N_R)^c=N_R$ (the defining condition for a field to be Majorana).

$\bullet$ I know that **after** diagonalization, the light, and heavy neutrinos will be linear combinations of the fields $\nu_L$ and $N_R$, and are all  Majorana particles. But my question is what can we say about the fields $N_R$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Dirac spinor can be written as the sum of two Weyl (chiral) spinors, eigenstates of $\gamma_5$,
$$
\psi= \psi_L + \psi_R,\tag{1}
$$
but also, alternatively, as the sum of two Majorana (self-conjugate) spinors, eigenstates of *C* (and $i\gamma_2$)
$$ 
\psi= \chi + i\omega= \chi^c + i\omega^c,\tag{2}
$$
where each Majorana component is real in the Majorana representation, in which 
$\gamma_5= \sigma^3\otimes \sigma^2$, imaginary, $i\gamma_2= \sigma^2\otimes\sigma^2$, real, and $C=-i\sigma^1\otimes \sigma^2$, real. Note *C* and $i\gamma_2$ do not commute with $\gamma_5$ (a feature of 4 dimensions).

Consequently, ***a Majorana spinor cannot be Weyl***, and ***a Weyl spinor cannot be Majorana***. The Majorana and Weyl bases are mutually exclusive bases for the components of a Dirac spinor.

$N_R$ is a Weyl spinor, and combines with $\nu_L$ to resolve into two Majorana components. Don't worry about *N* vs *ν*, they are meant to recall EW quantum numbers.

---

A comprehensive treatment is in section 13.2 of ISBN-13: 978-0198506218,
*Gauge Theory of Elementary Particle Physics: Problems and Solutions*, 1st Edition
by Ta-Pei Cheng &  Ling-Fong Li.

*Edit as per references request* : [M Schwartz's notes](http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic1146664.files/II-4-CPT.pdf), authoritative alright,  illustrate the link in the Weyl, not Majorana basis, where everything is complex, instead, so contrast eqns (9) to (34).

Answer (score -1):

The answer sits in the definition of charge conjugation as:

$$\psi^c = C \bar{\psi}^T$$

where $C$ is some ''book dependent matrix''. In many notes, it is chosen to be $i\gamma_2$ but this will be irrelevant for our discussion.

With this in mind, we can now rewrite the action from your question as:

$$-\mathcal{L} = \bar{\nu_L} m_D N_R + \frac{1}{2}C (N_R)^T M_R N_R + h.c.$$

At which point is becomes very clear that $N_R$ is indeed a Majorana neutrino.

Comment: You can also define $\psi^c$ for a Dirac field $\psi$. It's just that $\psi\neq \psi^c$ for a Dirac field. Therefore, the presence of $\psi^c$ in the Lagrangian doesn't ensure that $\psi$ is a Majorana neutrino. @gertian

Comment: I agree, my point was that $\bar{\psi}^c \sim \psi^T$ it is just a strange way to write down the transpose of your field.
If you look in this paper you will find that they use the Lagrangian that I obtained after the substitution: https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/9911364.pdf

Comment: As soon as you write down a Majorana mass term for it you have implicitly assumed that it must obey $\psi^c = \psi$ otherwise you would lose the symmetries in your theory.

Comment: I'm not convinced (although you may be correct). Nowhere you need to assume $(N_R)^c=N_R$. And it appears to me that you write the Majorana mass term because it is compatible with Lorentz invariance and gauge invariance. @gertian

Comment: Yes indeed you write the Majorana term becouse it is compatible with your gauge (and Lorentz) invariance if and only if $(N_R)^c = N_R$.
But to be fairly honest the exact reason why that is the case sits way to far back in my head...(and I am nearing deadline on my thesis so I can't really take the time to look it up.)